# Logging errors/exceptions with log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I'm trying to log all exceptions to a sql server database through log4net, and I've seen some posts here explaining how to properly configure the web.config file, but my question is: do it is enough to get the exception logged (the application will log automatically, but in this case it does not work on my app), or do I have to call the logger from code-behind into try/catch statement?

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Thanks a lot,
Epros

Answer (score 1):

You can user Application_Error in global.asax. This is called when an unhandler error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to auto-catch, you need to hook up your unhandled exception to do the logging (in the same way you'd hook it up to do any other global exception management).

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367967/log4net-log-all-application-errors/1368089#1368089) might help.