# log4net log all unhandled application errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, log4net

Can you point me to some tutorial or samples on how I can log all **un-handled exceptions** that are occurring on my mvc web app using log4net. Thank you

Comment: You may or may not find this interesting (I'm not sure if it will work with log4net): ELMAH - http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: Thanks! I actually also hooked my app to Elmah while working on this problem and I really like the handy interface it has. I see my self using it more compared to log4 net for now but I will see how that goes with more experience..

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I paste below the code I use on my global.asax that seems to satisfy me for now.. I am getting all unhandled exceptions on my log4net generated log files..

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));

        void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

            log.Error("App_Error", ex);
        }


        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        }

    }
```

Comment: You can also use an HttpModule to register the Error event handler: http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2006/06/12/146356.aspx

Comment: You'll want to add 
`routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });` to your RegisterRoutes method if you don't have a favicon located within your site

Comment: About HttpModule: the method to register the module detailed in the linked article applies to the old Classic IIS pipeline mode, not the (now recommended) integrated mode. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx for details on how to register it if you use integrated mode.

Comment: So where do exceptions get logged to in this case?

Answer (score 7):

For ASP.NET applications you like to use the `System.Web.HttpApplication.Error` event which is placed in `Global.asax` file.

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    // Stop error from displaying on the client browser
    Context.ClearError();

    logger.Fatal(ex.ToString);

}
```

watch [Managing unhandled exceptions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2949/Managing-Unhandled-Exceptions-in-NET)

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested to check out what [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (AOP) is.

We accomplished this with [Post sharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) (only - we didn't use log4net but custom tracer).

Just check out first if log4net haven't something for this 'out-of-the-box'. I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in support for this in log4net. You should implement [the Application_Error event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwzzh56s.aspx) in Global.asax and call your log4net logger there. The event will be triggered for all unhandled events in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Without being facetious [here you go](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html).

```
        try
        {
            NotImplementedException nie = new NotImplementedException();
            throw nie;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Fatal(e);
        }
```

Assuming you are using .net 3.5, you could use extension methods, and extend System.Exception and add a Log(log4net.ILog log) method, then wherever you catch an exception in your app, assuming you've setup the Log instance correctly, then you easily do it. Your extension class could grow quite a bit, with various overloads for Debug, Info, Warn, Error and Fatal etc.

Comment: sorry my question was not clear - I need to log all unhandled exceptions