# log4net catch all controller action errors for web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, log4net

I am currently implementing log4net for catching my exceptions for web api controller.

I wanted to know how could i potentially catch all errors in any action within the controller?

I did not want to go through each action ideally and add try catch if it can be helped?

Comment: For unhandled exceptions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367967/log4net-log-all-unhandled-application-errors

Comment: Is that question about "ASP.NET Web API"? If so, consider adding the [asp.net-web-api] tag.

Comment: Oh, and if so, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16028919/21567) might be the answer.

Comment: Cheers will need to catch exceptions on the web api server ideally to aid if we have any issues on the live system. Not sure if tracing will work with this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to register an [IExceptionLogger](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Global%20Error%20Handling)

e.x.: GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new YourWebApiExceptionLogger());

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute. In the OnActionExecuted you can handle your logging:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
            if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
            {
              //ok
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.ErrorFormat("actionExecutedContext.Response == null will result in 500, unhandled exception"); //Add extra information here
            }
    }
```

Then you can add this ActionFilter as attribute to the methods you want to log.