# 500 Server Error - IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

My web page is getting 500 Server Error inconsistently. And when i restart my IIS(7.5), it temporarily solves the issue. Is there a way to find out why?

Am using Custom error Mode.
As per below solution:
[Deploying website: 500 - Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error)
if I use detailed mode, the error log is getting displayed in my webpage to the user. Can we get error log in separate file while the error occurs with out displaying it in web page?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe better ask/search on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: So what is the (detailed) error message that's displayed?

Comment: search for information about error handling inside global.asax

Comment: The problem is might be in the data sources... Check and verify your Tables and Stored Procedures in database...

Comment: You need to add logging in the Application_Error, may I suggest using log4net. There are plenty examples on the internet, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367967/log4net-log-all-unhandled-application-errors