# how to create a new log file every time when the application starts using lo4net

Tags: logging, log4net, error-logging, rollingfileappender, log4net-appender

how to create a new log file every time when the application starts using lo4net. or I wanted to clear the log file each time. RollingFileAdapter doesn't give me any solution.
see my code:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="Log.txt"/>
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%identity - [%date] [%level] %class %method  %message %exception %newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

here I have to add anything or anything else?

Now I changed to this but I want a filename added with datetime for each execution.

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender"type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender"> 
  <file value="log\" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
  <appendToFile value="false" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="[%date] [%level] Class Name: %class Method Name: %method line No: %line %message %exception %newline" />
  </layout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4net one file per run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048844/log4net-one-file-per-run) or if you want to overwrite the existing file on each run, try setting AppendToFile = false

Comment: Yeah its working now Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new log file on each execution: rollingStyle -> once, and set appendtofile to false:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="Log.txt"/>
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="false" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
   <rollingStyle value="Once" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%identity - [%date] [%level] %class %method  %message %exception %newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: here I want to get a new file for every application starts but filename should be added with DateTime. Can you please help me out for this. check the updated question please.